# Peer could not connect to External Address of Orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When I update the external address of orderer address, everything works fine, latest block has external address value. Although remote peer can telnet to external address, peer's log show peer could not connect to this.

Step to reproduce:
1. Fetch channel config.
2. Update config with newest config.
3. Sign channel of orderer, organization.
4. Update channel config.
5. Join channel and sync data.

Logs show like this:

```
2019-05-15 06:44:58.561 UTC [gossip/service] func1 -> INFO 0a3 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel rmchannel
2019-05-15 06:45:01.562 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 0a4 Failed connecting to internal-add:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-05-15 06:45:04.563 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 0a5 Failed connecting to external-add:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-05-15 06:45:04.563 UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 0a6 Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [internal-add:7050 external-add:7050]
2019-05-15 06:45:04.563 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 0a7 Got error: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [internal-add:7050 external-add:7050] , at 1 attempt. Retrying in 1s
2019-05-15 06:45:08.565 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 0a8 Failed connecting to external-add:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-05-15 06:45:11.566 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 0a9 Failed connecting to internal-add:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-05-15 06:45:11.566 UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 0aa Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [external-add:7050]
2019-05-15 06:45:11.566 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 0ab Got error: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [external-add:7050] , at 2 attempt. Retrying in 2s
```

Could anyone have ideas about my case?
Many thanks!

Comment: Run the peer with environment variable of FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=grpc=debug:info and then see what it prints. it could be a TLS issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's much more clear now. It show:   

`2019-05-15 09:35:20.903 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 15c grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to external address}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate is valid for internal address, not external address". Reconnecting...`

What should I do? I add extra orderer with hostname same as external address with cryptogen extend --config, right?

Comment: you need to put additional SANs in the crypto-config.yaml

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I'm trying to add SANs, but remote peer still show same error: `authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate is valid for internal address, not external address`. When I run `cryptogen generate --config /shared/config-test/artifacts/orderer-sans-crypto-config.yaml`, it create new cert and override to exist folder. Here is my crypto-config
---
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: orderer-test
    Specs:
    - Hostname: orderer0
      SANS:
        - '{{.Hostname}}.{{.Domain}}'
        - 'external-address.com'

Comment: Here is my crypto-config certificate folder, I keep root folder and cut all cert file because commend can't add too much characters:
orderer-test/  
|-- ca
|-- msp
|-- orderers
|   `-- orderer0.orderer-test
|       |-- msp
|       `-- tls
|-- tlsca
`-- users
    `-- Admin@orderer-test
        |-- msp
        `-- tls